# Where is the copy local option?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

I'm trying to add dll references to an ASP.NET 3.5 project(Web Forms not MVC), and all of the references I'm adding keep showing up as auto updating.  I right clicked on the dll in the bin folder to specify copy local, but the option isn't there.

I went back to one of 2.0 projects, and I have plenty of dll's that aren't auto updating, but I can't figure out how to add a reference that isn't auto updating anymore...

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's in the same spot for you (I use Studio 2005, .NET 2.0) but for me, for a normal app, I expand the References node and click the reference. The properties display, and it's there as Copy Local. (not the dll in bin, the reference in the Reference node in project explorer)